# Is a clustered index on column A the same as creating a table ordered by A?

Tags: postgresql, clustered-index, performance, postgresql-performance

Reading the [official PostgreSQL documentation for version 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-cluster.html) I read an interesting [escamotage](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/escamotage) that performs better than `CLUSTER` for big tables:

> The CLUSTER command reorders the original table by scanning it using the index you specify. This can be slow on large tables because the rows are fetched from the table in index order, and if the table is disordered, the entries are on random pages, so there is one disk page retrieved for every row moved. (PostgreSQL has a cache, but the majority of a big table will not fit in the cache.) The other way to cluster a table is to use:
>
> ```
>   CREATE TABLE newtable AS
>     SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY columnlist;
> ```
>
> which uses the PostgreSQL sorting code to produce the desired order; this is usually much faster than an index scan for disordered data. Then you drop the old table, use ALTER TABLE ... RENAME to rename newtable to the old name, and recreate the table's indexes. The big disadvantage of this approach is that it does not preserve OIDs, constraints, foreign key relationships, granted privileges, and other ancillary properties of the table — all such items must be manually recreated. Another disadvantage is that this way requires a sort temporary file about the same size as the table itself, so peak disk usage is about three times the table size instead of twice the table size.

The problem is that this suggestion doesn't appear in > 9.0 versions of the official documentation.

My question is if this escamotage is still valid for 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 and 9.4 because I'm stuck with a `CLUSTER` operation over two big tables (one has ~750M rows and the other one has ~1650M rows) and average disk write/read speed is 3MB/s due to the `CLUSTER` algorithm explained in the official doc. It's a slow process over big tables, so I'd like to avoid it doing the "create ordered table over index-associated-column" trick. This will save me days of DB processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Like @dezso commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93990/postgresql-9-x-a-clustered-index-on-column-a-is-the-same-as-creating-a-table-or#comment168350_93990), creating a new table and dropping the old used to be faster in old versions, but not any more with the new implementation in pg 9.1.

The most common problem with `CLUSTER` is that it requires an exclusive lock on the table, which does not go well with concurrent access to it.

The solution to *this* problem is [**`pg_repack`**](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack), which does not lock the table exclusively.

Generally, make sure that your [server configuration is fit for the task](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server). High settings (a lot of RAM) for [**`maintenance_work_mem`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAINTENANCE-WORK-MEM) would help both `CLUSTER` and `CREATE INDEX` on big tables. Standard setting is *way* too small for you. Follow the links for details.

You might set it very high temporarily for a transaction with `SET LOCAL` and leave it at a reasonable setting otherwise:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL maintenance_work_mem = ????MB; -- find the sweet spot
CLUSTER tbl;
COMMIT;
```

If possible, set it high enough to fit the whole operation in RAM.

More:

- [PostgreSQL 9.0 how to reclaim disk space after delete without rebuilding table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62969/postgresql-9-0-how-to-reclaim-disk-space-after-delete-without-rebuilding-table/62970#62970)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Thanks for your response. At [link](http://reorg.github.io/pg_repack/) there's the following notice: `Target table must have a PRIMARY KEY, or at least a UNIQUE total index on a NOT NULL column.`. My tables dont' satisfy this statement. Do you think that partitioning the tables will improve `CREATE INDEX` and `CLUSTER` performance?

Comment: @pietrop: Since your tables are so big, partitioning would probably help quite a bit for `CLUSTER`  and `CREATE INDEX`, smaller partitions can more easily be processed in RAM. But first check if optimizing your settings might do the job. I added some more to the answer.

Comment: I had yet set `maintenance_work_mem = 4GB` on a 8GB RAM machine and `maintenance_work_mem = 64GB` on a 128GB RAM machine, but I didn't notice any improvement. The bottleneck was the disk I/O because PostgreSQL was reading a lot of 8KB blocks instead of bigger ones, resulting in a low read speed (~3MB/S). Now I'm repopulating the DB using the partitioning method. As a reference point, it tooks a total time of 40seconds on a 3milion rows table to: 9x`CREATE...INHERITS`, 9x`INSERT`, 10x`VACUUM ANALYZE`, 1x`INDEX`, 1x`CLUSTER`, 3x`INDEX`, 10x`VACUUM ANALYZE`. I'm expecting 6 hours for 1650mln rows