# Does cancelling (stopping early) a CLUSTER command cause a full rollback in Postgres 9.5?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Let's say I want to `CLUSTER` a table.  There's no way to know how long it will take so I just run it.  After a couple hours, I need the data so I cancel the `CLUSTER` command.  Does CLUSTERing work with temp tables/files such that if I cancel before it's finished, all of that is erased and the hours it ran are wasted or does it make changes "live" such that canceling after a few hours isn't a full waste of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you called `CLUSTER` without parameters you cannot [`ROLLBACK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-rollback.html) at all since that is only applicable to transactions. [Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html)

> This form of `CLUSTER` cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

But you talk about *"`CLUSTER` a table"*, so assuming you mean the form:

```
CLUSTER table_name [ USING index_name ]
```

Which is transactional. Cancelling this command should **not do any harm**. Postgres builds the new table (and indexes) in the background and only updates references to physical files when done. [The manual again:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html)

> When an index scan is used, **a temporary copy of the table is created**
>   that contains the table data in the index order. **Temporary copies of
>   each index** on the table are created as well. Therefore, you need free
>   space on disk at least equal to the sum of the table size and the
>   index sizes.
>
> When a sequential scan and sort is used, **a temporary sort file is also
>   created**, so that the peak temporary space requirement is as much as
>   double the table size, plus the index sizes. [...]

Bold emphasis mine. But the work that went into the temp tables is lost when you cancel the command before it can finish.

`CLUSTER` does not even update table statistics, which is why you should probably run `ANALYZE` on the table after `CLUSTER`.

Concerning:

> *I need the data so I cancel the `CLUSTER` command.*

You might be interested in [**`pg_repack`**](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack), which can do the same as `CLUSTER` without exclusive locks, so you can use it without painting yourself into a corner - or even when you cannot afford downtime at all.

The extension is not shipped with Postgres, though. You have to install it yourself. It's not available on many cloud services.

Related:

- [Is a clustered index on column A the same as creating a table ordered by A?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93990/is-a-clustered-index-on-column-a-the-same-as-creating-a-table-ordered-by-a/94058#94058)